# Linear Algebra - Determine if the following 2 subspaces add up to $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

$W_1=\{ (0,-b,b)|\ b\in \mathbb R$}

$W_2=\{(a_1, a_1+a_2,a_2)\;|\ a_1,a_2\in \mathbb R\}$

Is $\mathbb R^3=W_1+W_2$?

I know that if it is true, then $\mathbb R^3\subset W_1+W_2$. How do I determine whether the 2 subspaces span $\mathbb R^3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $W_1$ has dimension $1$ while $W_2$ has dimension $2$. Thus, they will sum up to $\Bbb R^3\iff W_1\cap W_2=\{(0,0,0)\}$.

Comment: Yes thank you Pedro!